# Pull an item from all arrays MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, discord, discord.js

idk if this is possible but need some help with mongo, I have the following document, and I want to make it so I can use `$addToSet` to add a value to one of the items in `votes`, but remove that item from all the other items in `votes` but have no idea how

```js
{
  _id: '872952643117518909',
  questions: [
    { question: 'a', number: 1, dropDownInfo: [Object] },
    { question: 'b', number: 2, dropDownInfo: [Object] },
    { question: 'c', number: 3, dropDownInfo: [Object] }
  ],
  votes: {
    '1': [ '619284841187246090', '662697094104219678' ],
    '2': [ '619284841187246090', '662697094104219678' ],
    '3': [ '662697094104219678', '619284841187246090' ]
  },
  question: 'abc',
  timestamp: 1628198528903,
  finished: false,
  channel: '812038854302892064'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The bellow pipeline adds a vote('619284841187246090') to a specific field,here randomly "2" was chosen,and removes that vote from "1" and "3" array.

Solution is general,can work with any vote fields not just "1" "2" "3".

You can use this pipeline in aggregation or update with pipeline (Mongodb>=4.2)

`$addToSet` doesn't work in arrays, it works when grouping and
in some other places in MongoDB 5.

I think your schema has a problem, because you are saving data in the schema, and that makes querying harder and creating indexing harder etc.

But we can still do it converting the object to array and back to object.

I think its best to keep data in arrays,and fields to be the known schema.

You can run the bellow code [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CudqK-2vjEf)

Query

```json
db.collection.aggregate( [ {
    "$addFields" : {
      "votes" : {
        "$arrayToObject" : {
          "$map" : {
            "input" : {
              "$map" : {
                "input" : {
                  "$objectToArray" : "$votes"
                },
                "as" : "m",
                "in" : [ "$$m.k", "$$m.v" ]
              }
            },
            "as" : "vote",
            "in" : {
              "$cond" : [ {
                "$eq" : [ {
                  "$arrayElemAt" : [ "$$vote", 0 ]
                }, "2" ]
              }, [ {
                "$arrayElemAt" : [ "$$vote", 0 ]
              }, {
                "$cond" : [ {
                  "$in" : [ "619284841187246090", {
                    "$arrayElemAt" : [ "$$vote", 1 ]
                  } ]
                }, {
                  "$arrayElemAt" : [ "$$vote", 1 ]
                }, {
                  "$concatArrays" : [ {
                    "$arrayElemAt" : [ "$$vote", 1 ]
                  }, [ "619284841187246090" ] ]
                } ]
              } ], [ {
                "$arrayElemAt" : [ "$$vote", 0 ]
              }, {
                "$filter" : {
                  "input" : {
                    "$arrayElemAt" : [ "$$vote", 1 ]
                  },
                  "as" : "v",
                  "cond" : {
                    "$not" : [ {
                      "$eq" : [ "$$v", "619284841187246090" ]
                    } ]
                  }
                }
              } ] ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } ])
```

Results

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "872952643117518909",
    "channel": "812038854302892064",
    "finished": false,
    "question": "abc",
    "questions": [
      {
        "dropDownInfo": "",
        "number": 1,
        "question": "a"
      },
      {
        "dropDownInfo": "",
        "number": 2,
        "question": "b"
      },
      {
        "dropDownInfo": "",
        "number": 3,
        "question": "c"
      }
    ],
    "timestamp": 1.628198528903e+12,
    "votes": {
      "1": [
        "662697094104219678"
      ],
      "2": [
        "619284841187246090",
        "662697094104219678"
      ],
      "3": [
        "662697094104219678"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```